# Dynamically remove elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic, element

I got a javascript with a function that creates a table. Now I want the table to be updated/replaced each time I press the button again. I have tried some solutions I have found on the web but none seem to do what I want.

*javascript*

```
  //Updates table
function myFunction(jsonObject) {

//Build array from the jsonObject
var customers = new Array();
var jsonArr = jsonObject['log'];
for(var i in jsonArr){
    customers.push((jsonArr[i]['date']) );
    customers.push((jsonArr[i]['time']) );
    customers.push((jsonArr[i]['temp']) );
    customers.push((jsonArr[i]['humidity']) );
}



//Remove existing tables.-----------------------THIS HAS NO EFFECT!
var myNode = document.getElementById('logDiv');
while (myNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        alert("logDiv has nodes, removing them now!")
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
}
//----------------------------------------------THIS HAS NO EFFECT!



var container = document.getElementById('logDiv');
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
table.className = "sortable";

//Adds table headers
var headers = ["Date", "Time", "Temp", "Hum"]
var row1 = document.createElement('tr');
for (var b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
    var cell = document.createElement('th');
    cell.textContent = headers[b];
    row1.appendChild(cell);
    counter++;
}
tbody.appendChild(row1);

var counter = 0;
// loop and create rows
for (i = 0; i < customers.length/4; i++) {
    var values = customers[i];
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    // loop and create columns
    for (var b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.textContent = customers[counter];
        row.appendChild(cell);
        counter++;
    }
    tbody.appendChild(row);
}
table.appendChild(tbody);
container.appendChild(table);
}
```

*html/php*

```
   <?php
    $logLines = file('../../../home/shares/flower_hum/humid.log');
    $entries = array_map("clean",$logLines);
    $finalOutput = ['log'  => $entries];
    function clean($string){
        return json_decode(rtrim(trim($string),','),true);
    }

    $json = json_encode($finalOutput);
    ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Antgus</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btnGenerate" type="button" onclick='myFunction(<?php echo $json ?>)'>Generate log</button>
        <br><br>
        <div id="logDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm patiently waiting for the first "use jQuery"-reply...

Comment: Why is tagged as "php"?

Comment: If you want to construct the table by creating / appending DOM elements you better first do it under a document fragment and once you have it ready append it under the table container div  within a `requestAnimationFrame()` call